# How to add an instantiated objects to the DOM? Simulating React in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to complete an optional project for my class, we have been using React for the past month or so and I have become pretty comfortable with the framework. Though, in order to actually have a better understanding of how things are actually working under the hood, I am trying to recreate the process of instantiating objects and rendering them on the page with vanilla JavaScript.

I'm posting now because I've hit a wall and I'm having difficulty finding helpful material online.

In the following code I have successfully querySelected my inputs and a button, I want to render an object onto the page that displays unique instance of the `Idea` class. The object comes with some buttons: favorite, delete, upvote, and downvote.

What I've managed to accomplish so far:

1. target the DOM elements and capture their inputs
2. instantiate an object with the input values and push it into an array

What I am attempting to do:

1. render each object element in the `ideas` array to the DOM
2. Be able to click the buttons on the rendered output and change the state of that respective object + remove the correct object on click.

The current logic I've written so far:

```
//buttons
const saveButton = document.querySelector(".save-button");

//inputs
const titleInput = document.querySelector("[name='title']");
const bodyInput = document.querySelector("[name='body']");

//output
const outputSection = document.querySelector(".main-outputs");

let titleValue = "";
let bodyValue = "";
const ideas = [];

titleInput.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  titleValue = "";
  titleValue += e.target.value;
});

bodyInput.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  bodyValue = "";
  bodyValue += e.target.value;
});

saveButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const ideaObject = new Idea(titleValue, bodyValue);
  ideas.push(ideaObject);
  console.log("ideas: ", ideas);
  render(ideaObject, outputSection);
});

const render = function(template, node) {
  if (!node) return;
  node.innerHTML += template;
};

class Idea {
  constructor(title, body) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.favorite = false;
    this.quality = "swill";
    this.id = Date.now();
    this.content = this.content;
  }

  renderIdea() {}
}
```

The html each element 'should' render on the page.

```html
        <article class="main-output-card">
          <header>
            <img src="./icons/star.svg" alt="" />
            <img src="./icons/delete.svg" alt="" />
          </header>
          <section>
            <h3 class="idea-title">Idea Title</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque
              consectetur voluptas fuga accusantium!
            </p>
          </section>
          <footer>
            <img src="./icons/upvote.svg" alt="" />
            <h5 class="idea-quality">Quality: <span>Swill</span></h5>
            <img src="./icons/downvote.svg" alt="" />
          </footer>
        </article>
```

Any help would be appreciated, it seems like a good challenge but I feel like I'm in over my head.

Would love to see what I should do / what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Is `renderIdea() {}` a magical method?

Comment: One route would be to review the source code for React itself--especially if you go to the early versions, you might find some easy to understand code. Alternatively, there are other libraries that mimic what React does. Preact, for example, is a 3KB drop-in replacement for React, so I'd imagine its source code is relatively lean and straightforward. On React itself, there might even be early material (documentation, blog posts, talks, etc.) that describe the approach the team at Facebook took.

Answer (score 1):

The code has a lot of gaps. Here are some thoughts:

You seem to be intending to inject some values in a html template which is in the browser, by changing the inner html of it. This will mean that you will only be able to add one element to your page, as you are not creating new elements.
You will need to create more DOM elements if you want to have multiple 'Ideas' being displayed.

Generating new DOM elements can be achieved by [cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the node you want to use.
 Or you might make a constructor for the DOM elements using the [create method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Once you have you DOM element you can insert into the page by using one of the [various insertion methods.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

A way to make changes to each of the element would be to simply give each an id, and selecting each of them by id and performing the desired changes to them.

To delete the correct element after a certain click event, you can use the properties on the event object, in particular event.target, to find which element was clicked.

The heuristics of syncing the state and the DOM I'll leave it up to you.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you are wanting to render the entire thing from scratch (I assume you are), then you could do this. It is all vanilla JavaScript, no JQuery or anything like that.

There is 1 VERY important thing to remember though. Just like with React, Vue, etc., if the user has JavaScript disabled in their browser, they will see nothing when they open the page.

```js
/* your other existing functions */

const createImg = function(src, alt) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', src);
  img.setAttribute('alt', alt);

  return img;
}

const createTextElement = function (type, text, className) {
  let el = document.createElement(type);
  el.innerText = text;
  if (className) el.className = className;
}

class Idea {
  constructor(title, body) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.favorite = false;
    this.quality = "swill";
    this.id = Date.now();
    this.content = this.content;
  }

  renderIdea() {
    // Create the main container
    let article = document.createElement('article');
    article.className = 'main-output-card';

    // Create the header container and add the icons to it
    let articleHeader = document.createElement('header');
    articleHeader.appendChild(createImg('./icons/star.svg', ''));
    articleHeader.appendChild(createImg('./icons/delete.svg', ''));

    // Create the content section and add the content to it
    let articleSection = document.createElement('section');
    articleSection.appendChild(createTextElement('h3', this.title, 'idea-title'));
    articleSection.appendChild(createTextElement('p', this.body));

    // Create the article footer and add content to it
    articleFooter = document.createElement('footer');

    let articleFooterQuality = document.createElement('h5');
    articleFooterQuality.className = 'idea-quality';
    articleFooterQuality.innerHtml = `Quality: <span>${this.quality}</span>`;

    articleFooter.appendChild(createImg('./icons/upvote.svg', ''));
    articleFooter.appendChild(articleFooterQuality);
    articleFooter.appendChild(createImg('./icons/downvote.svg', ''));
  }
}
```